# calculate count based on existence of field value in every id : MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data as below

```
id       desc
1       error 1
1       captured
1       closed
2       captured
2       closed
3       closed
```

expected output is: For each id, if there is the description "error 1", it should a count in group A else in group B.

```
A      B
1      2
```

My query so far is checking one above and one below.

```
select sum(A) as TW, sum(B) as B
from (
select 
case when lower(Description) like '%error 1%' then 1 end as A,

case when lg_description  not like '%error 1%' 
and ld_desc not like '%error 1%'
 then 1 end as B
from (
select  Description,
              lag(Description)  
                over (partition by DSurveillanceAssetFaultID order by TimestampUTC) as lg_description,
                lead(Description)  
                over (partition by  DSurveillanceAssetFaultID order by TimestampUTC) as ld_desc
        from  #temp1) a
)b
group by Format(TimestampUTC, 'MMMM-yyyy')
```

Comment: Else 0  could help cause sum and null could create issues.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select count(distinct case when description = 'error 1' then id end) as A
       count(distinct id) 
        - count(distinct case when description = 'error 1' then id end) as B
  from your_Table t
```